# jquery - how to add/remove class on slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, slide

I would like to each time the div expands, to add the class 'selecionado' once the expansion is finished. 
When the contraction is done (the slideUp part) I would like to remove this class.

Can I have a help here please?

```
$('#btCategoriaA').click(function()
{
  $('#listaCategoriaA').slideToggle('slow', function() {
   $('#btCategoriaA').addClass('selecionado');
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can toggle the class using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) based on if the element [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) after the animation, like this:

```
$('#btCategoriaA').click(function() {
  $('#listaCategoriaA').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    $('#btCategoriaA').toggleClass('selecionado', $(this).is(':visible'));
  });
});
```

Comment: You really rock on js don't you? :P Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: One more thing please, I'm doing this using using css states like a:hover. The thing is, I need to disable the hover, once the user clicks, otherwise, the effect will be quite weird, because once it clicks the state should change, but since it's hovered, it doesn't. :s Is there a way to disable the a:hover applied once the user clicks or something?

Comment: @MEM - You can have the `:hover` as `a.Off:hover` and remove that `Off` class when adding the `selecionado` one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065786/disable-ahover-styles-when-some-element-is-visible

Comment: @Nick Craver: So, the a.Off:hover will NOT apply the hover effect. Once we remove the Off part, the hover will be applied, is that the trick?

Comment: @MEM - it should start off with the `Off` class, then when it's removed it'll no longer be `a.Off`, so the `:hover` on that class won't work, make sense?

Comment: @Nick Craver: I'm to tired or I'm to dummy do get it. :( Care to update your js answer with the css part so that I can study it and understand what you mean?

Comment: @Nick Craver: No I haven't! OMG. :(