# Disable a:hover styles when some element is visible;

Tags: jquery, css

Thanks to Nick Craver, I got this working. What it does, it shows hides a class based on the visible state of something.

```
$('#btCategoriaA').click(function() {
  $('#listaCategoriaA').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    $('#btCategoriaA').toggleClass('selecionado', $(this).is(':visible'));
  });
});
```

Based on the same visible of that something, I would like to "disable" the a:hover, or to empty the a:hover lines... not sure how. The point is: If something is visible, to NOT apply the a:hover of my css.

Any clue here?

**EDIT**
I have the following css:

```
#listaCategorias li.categoriaA a:hover {
    background-position: 0px -79px;
}

#listaCategorias li.categoriaA a:active {
    background-position: 0px -158px;
}

#listaCategorias li.categoriaA .selecionado {
    background-position: 0px -158px;
}
```

And the HTML part:

```
<ul id="listaCategorias">
  <li class="categoriaA"><a id="btCategoriaA" href="#">Categoria A</a></li>
  <li class="categoriaB"><a id="btCategoriaB" href="#">Categoria B</a></li>
  <li class="categoriaC"><a id="btCategoriaC" href="#">Categoria C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just give that new class with `:hover` the original styling, for example:

```
a, a.selecionado:hover { color: black }
a:hover { color: red; }
```

This way the `a.selecionado:hover` selector is more specific, so the original non-hover styling wins out.

Comment: I have updated my question with more code, maybe from there it could be easy to get this... :s With the code about, what would you do?

Comment: @MEM - add to your selector, make `#listaCategorias li.categoriaA a:active` into `#listaCategorias li.categoriaA a:active, #listaCategorias li.categoriaA a.selecionado:hover` so the position sticks even when hovering that more specific selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Since this is a slideDown effect it takes some time to the visibility to be "on" if you could understand me. I'm tempted to try with the .click. So, instead of having the $(this).is(':visible')); can we have $(this).click ?

Comment: This is changing the class only when the slideUp or slideDown ENDS. So, I changed the order so that ON CLICK he changes the class, and THEN, do the slide. This almost work: it works for the slideDown part, but, the class doesn't toogle on slideUp. :( $('#btCategoriaA').click(function() {
        $('#btCategoriaA').toggleClass('selecionado', $(this).is(':visible'));
        $('#listaCategoriaA').slideToggle('slow', function() {
           });
        });

Comment: I end up with something like this: $('#btCategoriaA').click(function() {
            $('#btCategoriaA').toggleClass('selecionado');
        $('#listaCategoriaA').slideToggle('slow', function() {
           });
        }); So, I've removed the is visible part since if I do that the class will only be applied when the animation ends and that delay was not intended. THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR PATIENCE. :D

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to change the `a:hover` selector to `a.selecionado:hover`, which will cause the `:hover` rules to only match the element if it has that class.

**EDIT**:
*Javascript:*

```
$('#btCategoriaA').toggleClass('selecionado', $(this).is(':visible'));
$('#btCategoriaA').toggleClass('NotSelected', !$(this).is(':visible'));
```

*CSS:*

```
a.NotSelected:hover {
    color: pink;
}
```

Comment: @SLaks - Thanks. And what could that mean in terms of js code?

Comment: @MEM: Nothing.  Just change the CSS.

Comment: @SLaks - I SEE!! Since that class will only be applied on the desired condition, we change the css to ALSO apply that hover effect on the same desired condition. Is that it? :D

Comment: I got the opposite of the desired effect. :(

Comment: @MEM: Then you can add a second class and toggle it inversely.  (eg, `a.NotSelected:hover { ... }`).

Comment: @Slaks - Care do give a small example of that so that I can study it please? :)

Comment: This is way old, I know, but I ran into the same issue recently - just getting started with jQuery/js. Regarding getting the opposite effect from `.is(':visible')`, I was able to just do: `$('element').toggleClass('className, $('element:visible'));`